# How to convert an Observable model class for database storage

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ngrx

new to ngrx.

I read an article at http://lukajcb.github.io/blog/angular2/2016/04/02/frp-in-angular-2.html

The model used is as follows:

```
export class Person {
    name: Observable<string> = Observable.create();
    bmi: Observable<number> = Observable.create();
    category: Observable<string> = Observable.create();
}
```

I followed the article and understood it. However, I could not figure out how to store the model in a database, like Firebase. I would like to store primitives and objects containing primitives.

Can anyone suggest some reasonable options as to how best this could be accomplished?

Thanks